# What's the benefit of loading babel when writing in English?

Tags: hyphenation, babel

When writing in English what is the benefit of loading `babel`, by `\usepackage[english]{babel}`, except for the possibility of setting it to use specific English dialects as described in [babel: english, american, USenglish](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12775/babel-english-american-usenglish)?

For example I know that `biblatex`, `csquotes` and `microtype` can work together with `babel` but their features seems to only make sense when writing in other languages than in English.

Comment: you do not need babel, when you have a complete document in english.

Comment: @Herbert: You do if you are in the UK

Comment: sure, but that is not the option english from default TeX

Comment: So it depends on whether your entire document is in English or in `english`.

Comment: @doncherry I don't understand your comment. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @N.N.: I was just joking a bit on how Herbert and Joseph used different meanings of "English": Herbert was referring to the LaTeX  option `english`, which means _American English_, and Joseph was referring to the language English, which in Joseph's case means _British English_. Essentially, there's a reason for using `babel` if you're writing in British English (Joseph's point), and (according to Herbert) you don't need it if you're writing in American English.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should load **babel** if you're unsure about the default language. A system administrator in the UK may well have changed it to British English instead of US English (they have different hyphenation rules).

Assuming TeX Live is used (but also MiKTeX, I believe), lines such as

```
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
```

will guarantee that the requested hyphenation rules are used during typesetting. Another use for **babel** is for choosing a not directly supported set of hyphenation patterns; for example,

```
\usepackage{hyphsubst}
\HyphSubstLet{english}{usenglishmax}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

will use the "maximal set" of US English hyphenation patterns (check your `language.dat` file for the exact string to use, `usenglishmax` is surely correct for TeX Live).

Comment: Moreover, `USenglish` and `UKenglish` differ in the way quotation marks are used. For instance, `\enquote` of the `csquotes` package surrounds text with double quotation marks in case of `USenglish`, but with single quotation marks in case of `UKenglish`.

Answer (score 43):

Besides guaranteed proper hyphenation, if you load babel, you could access various useful shorthands related to hyphenation, such as provided by `ngerman`, even with `english` option:

- `\-` hyphenation with suppressed hyphenation before and after the break point
- `"-` hyphenation with enabled automatic hyphenation before and after the break point
- `""` for a hyphenation point without hyphen
- `"|` like `"-` but with disabling ligatures, adding a small space
- `-` (divis) for combined words
- `"~` for a dash where hyphenation is not allowed
- `"-` for a dash where hyphenation is allowed, also before and after

For example:

```
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
```

This has been asked and solved here: [Adding `ngerman`s language shorthands to `english` as the main document language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/babel-adding-ngermans-language-shorthands-to-english-as-the-main-document-la).