# LaTeX not hyphenating properly, text running off page

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I'm having a problem with LaTeX not hyphenating `$\beta$-galactosidase`, and the word as a result running off the page.

I have narrowed down the problem to a particular package, as a bare minumum LaTeX preamble with no packages avoids this problem.  Please help me to identify the offending package by process of elimination, and suggest a solution that retains the use of the package where possible.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
Finally, all of the three antibiotics examined had a negative effect on $\beta$-galactosidase activity from the time they were introduced to the assay.  It is to be noted that chloramphenicol interferes with the 50S ribosomal subunit which negatively implicates peptide bond formation~\cite{chloram1962}, streptomycin interrupts the initiation stage of protein synthesis~\cite{strepto1968}, while rifampicin is an RNA-polymerase inhibitor~\cite{rifam1983}.  These results verify that both transcription and translation are needed for the gene product $\beta$-galactosidase to arise, which is probably not much more than a validation of the flow of genetic information in accordance with central dogma.  An interruption at the transcription or translational stage would prematurely or directly halt the production of $\beta$-galactosidase, in the two respective cases.
\end{document}
```

Sample output:

[image]

Comment: Just note that the provided preamble is not minimal: As a start, you are loading `hypcap` twice.

Comment: I'd like to put some attention to this: the solutions provided here work very well for single words. But in some (dutch for example) languages there are many words that must be hyphenated when put behind each other. So hyphens are a natural occurence, adding all those word combinations to the exception lists is not going to work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that TeX doesn't know how to hyphenate the word `$\beta$-galactosidase` because it has a `$\beta$-` attached to it.  The best solution to this problem is to load the [`hyphenat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyphenat) package, and use `\hyp{}` instead of the `-`:

```
\usepackage{hyphenat}
$\beta$\hyp{}galactosidase
```

This tells the hyphenation to hyphenate the word after the `\hyp{}` as a regular word.

Comment: I'm very pleased with the diversity of responses, as their are multiple workable solutions to this problem.  Thank you to all who have put forward a solution.  I submitted my paper today, thankfully having corrected this quirk in time.  However, I'll acknowledge Alan's answer because it appears to be the most popular.

Answer (score 16):

Others have already pointed to the issue (the `\beta$-`). I'd like to point to the chemists answer: [`bpchem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bpchm). It includes the `\IUPAC` macro, inside which `\|` is a break point and `\-` is a breakable hyphen. This gives

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{bpchem,upgreek}

\begin{document}

Finally, all of the three antibiotics examined had a negative effect on
\IUPAC{$\upbeta$-galacto\|sidase} activity from the time they were introduced to
the assay. It is to be noted that chloramphenicol interferes with the 50S
ribosomal subunit which negatively implicates peptide bond
formation~\cite{chloram1962}, streptomycin interrupts the initiation stage of
protein synthesis~\cite{strepto1968}, while rifampicin is an RNA-polymerase
inhibitor~\cite{rifam1983}. These results verify that both transcription and
translation are needed for the gene product $\upbeta$-galactosidase to arise,
which is probably not much more than a validation of the flow of genetic
information in accordance with central dogma. An interruption at the
transcription or translational stage would prematurely or directly halt the
production of $\upbeta$-galactosidase, in the two respective cases.

\end{document}
```

(I've used `upgreek` as the use of italics for `\beta`, etc., in this text is wrong, but is often seen in the literature as the typesetting is done in TeX and upright greek letters need a little work!)

Comment: A chemist's input always appreciated.  Most of the documents I typeset are scientific or mathematical in nature, and quite a few of them are very chemistry-oriented.

Answer (score 6):

For what it is worth, ConTeXt MkIV correctly hyphenates words with `-`. I don't know the internal implementation, but it will be nice to have similar functionality with lualatex.

Here is a minimal example

```
\setupindenting[big,yes] % to get the same visual effect
\starttext
Finally, all of the three antibiotics examined had a negative effect on $\beta$-galactosidase activity from the time they were introduced to the assay.`
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image].

With regards to Joseph's suggestion of using \upbeta, if you are using a text font that has greek letters (like xits or cambria) you can simply type `β-galactosidase` and ConTeXt will hyphenate the word correctly.

Comment: I have added a LuaLaTeX solution...

Answer (score 6):

This LuaTeX solution is slightly more complicated: when the `pre_linebreak_filter` is called, the paragraph is already hyphenated. So you need to hyphenate again after inserting a `"=` equivalent. In order to hyphenate, all characters/glyphs must be subtype 1.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{luatexbase,luacode}

\begin{luacode}
local active_hyphen = function (head)
  local orig_head = head
  while head do
    if head.id == 37 then
      head.subtype = 1
      if head.char == 45 then
        local p = node.new("penalty")
        p.penalty = 10000
        local g = node.new("glue")
        g.spec = node.new("glue_spec")
        g.spec.width = 0

        head.prev.next = p

        p.next = head
        p.prev = head.prev

        g.prev = head
        g.next = head.next

        head.prev = p
        head.next = g

        g.next.prev = g
      end
    end
    head = head.next
  end
  lang.hyphenate(orig_head)
  return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",active_hyphen,"active-")

\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
Finally, all of the three antibiotics examined had a negative effect on $\beta$-galactosidase activity from the time they were introduced to the assay.  It is to be noted that chloramphenicol interferes with the 50S ribosomal subunit which negatively implicates peptide bond formation~\cite{chloram1962}, streptomycin interrupts the initiation stage of protein synthesis~\cite{strepto1968}, while rifampicin is an RNA-polymerase inhibitor~\cite{rifam1983}.  These results verify that both transcription and translation are needed for the gene product $\beta$-galactosidase to arise, which is probably not much more than a validation of the flow of genetic information in accordance with central dogma.  An interruption at the transcription or translational stage would prematurely or directly halt the production of $\beta$-galactosidase, in the two respective cases.
\end{document}
```

There are most likely other approaches to this problem using callbacks.

Answer (score 5):

If a word is already hyphenated, TeX won't hypenate it.  Here is one solution

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{ga-lac-to-si-dase}
\def\hyph{-\penalty0\hskip0pt\relax}

\begin{document}
Finally, all of the three antibiotics examined had a negative effect on $\beta$\hyph galactosidase activity from the time they were introduced to the assay.  It is to be noted that chloramphenicol interferes with the 50S ribosomal subunit which negatively implicates peptide .  
\end{document}
```

This is more of a MWE. If you put the hypen back you can reproduce the error.  If you are using this often it might be better to define a command for that:

```
\newcommand{\BetaGalactosidase}{$\beta$\hyph galactosidase}%
```

This is based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193307/how-to-get-latex-to-hyphenate-a-word-that-contains-a-dash

Answer (score 5):

A solution is to insert this into the preamble:

```
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasenglish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
```

and type `$\beta$"=galactosidase` - this inserts a hyphen and allows hyphenation in the next word. See [this answer to another question here on tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27740/whats-the-benefit-of-loading-babel-when-writing-in-english/27748#27748).

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is not package-related. It is the fact that the word "galactosidase" is not recognized in the hyphenation dictionary, and therefore does not have a proper hyphenation set. Consequently, LaTeX just typesets it as-is, without breaking it, causing the overflow into the margin. You need to suggest the discretionary hyphenation to LaTeX by using `\-` inside "galactosidase" at the appropriate places (say `ga\-lac\-to\-si\-dase`), or by specifying `\hyphenation{ga-lac-to-si-dase}` for a more global specification.

The latter may be problematic since the you are not using the word "galactosidase" on their won; you're prepending it with `$\beta$-`. Regardless, a work-around is the discretionary hyphenation `\-`.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The problem is caused by the `$\beta$-` attached to the word, which causes it not to be hyphenated independent of the the hyphenation points you specify.

Comment: @Alan: We were thinking the same thing; I mentioned this in my answer and suggested a more manual approach.