# Text flowing out in two column format

Tags: formatting, two-column, document-classes

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[sttt]{svjour}

\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}
%
\title{Title}

\author{Author}
%
%
\institute{Institute}
%
\date{Received: date / Revised version: date}

\maketitle
%
\begin{abstract}
Like NSSTs, functional NSSTs also allow non-deterministic transitions, but produce the same 
output string for every successful run on a given input. Like NSSTs, aaaa aa functional NSSTs also allow non-deterministic transitions, but produce the same 
output string for every successful run on a given input. 
\end{abstract}
%
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}
Your text comes here. Separate text sections with
\section{Section title}
\label{sec:1}

\subsection{Subsection title}
\label{sec:2}

\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

The text flowing out of the column due to hyphen. What is the solution to this?

Comment: Some reasoning behind *why* this is the case is available in [Why can words with hyphen char not be hyphenated?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63232/5764). Possible (local) duplicate(s): [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2706/5764); [LaTeX not hyphenating properly, text running off page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28136/5764)

Comment: I've duped here: there are several candidates as indicated and I've picked what I hope is the most general.