# two column style, text crossing middle

Tags: spacing, two-column

In my paper I wish to go for a two column style to "save pages" (there is an artificial limit of 8 pages, yet even by the prof said silliness of "prepared to wear glasses as long as it looks good").

So to have a good text we decided to go for a two column format "[paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121705/46904)" as we found it best looking.
However there are some major problems we found.

Most pressing is that the columns overlap, creating sometimes unreadable text.

In the following example:

```
\documentclass{paper} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext,graphicx,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\section{Fluid dynamics}

\subsection{Prediction models}
The accuracy with which parameters influence boundary-layer transition ranges from good to very low \cite{Tirtey}. Small changes in the shape and size of a roughness element has major influence on the hypersonic flow behavior \cite{Schneider}, and in combination with the very low accuracy of some paramaters, accurate prediction models are difficult to build. For hypersonic isolated 3D roughness-induced transition, three criteria named the Shuttle, Van Driest-Blumer and Potter-Whitfield are the most used correlations for predictions. However, all these criteria have used an certain assumption and therefore do not consider all aspects \cite{Tirtey}. In hypersonic wind tunnel experiments, the effect of a single roughness element on the flow can be investigated by changing a single parameter. It is important for hypersonic wind tunnel experiments to ensure other possible noise factors to be as low as possible since many will affect the results. Then, using the measurements results from the experiment, the physics behind a hypersonic flow becoming turbulent due to a roughness element can better be understand. 
\subsection{test}
\lipsum{500}

\end{document}
```

Te first line "The accuracy with which parameters influence boundary-" shows the problem. This line doesn't fit and it overlaps the lipsum. How can I make sure this is prevented?

Comment: TeX just doesn't know how to break those words (hyphenate them) across the column boundary. For words that TeX struggles with, supply a manual hyphenation pattern via `\-` or via `\hyphenation{<your hyphenation list>}` (globally). Alternatively, perhaps as a start, add `\sloppypar` to your preamble.

Comment: This is the very same problem as in [LaTeX not hyphenating properly, text running off page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28143/11002). I recommend to use either the answer by **Alan Munn** or the one by **topskip**.

Comment: please unmark - it also happens whith unhpyhenated words. I just didn't find it yet, but I do have seen it in text somewhere while creating the paper.

Comment: @paul23 In that case, edit your MWE to reflect this. Question about this have been here before as well, though. Btw, you're lucky that I saw your comment, I would recommend you to call me (or someone else for that matter) explicitly by writing `@yo'` somewhere in the comment next time, or I will miss it completely.

Comment: @paul23: By unhyphenated words are you referring to some of the Lorem Ipsum content? Those are just gibberish words.

Comment: No just some (often longer, say about half the column width in width) special words.