# How can I have word not fitting the margin moved to a new line?

Tags: line-breaking, margins

My problem is similar to: [LaTeX not hyphenating properly, text running off page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28136/latex-not-hyphenating-properly-text-running-off-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)
I have two column layout and some words extend beyond margin due to hyphenation issues.

**The difference is** that I do not want to hyphenate the trouble-making word. I want to have it automatically moved to a new line.

By automatically I mean I shall make no changes in the text within the column. You may imagine, that the text is to be written by someone else and inserted to my template with `\input{}`.

Comment: use `\sloppy` to allow more stretch of the white space

Comment: You can also employ `\raggedright`.

Comment: and  the `microtype` package. Nonetheless,  a two column layout without hyphenation is a bad idea.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\sloppy` works for me. I would like to accept your answer.

Comment: @Fran it is the lesser evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use use `\sloppy` to allow more stretch of the white space.