# Automatic hyphenation of compound words

Tags: hyphenation, babel, shorthands

When I was learning to drive a typewriter (shortly after the death of my pet sabre-tooth), I picked up the habit of using a double hyphen when splitting compound words, thus:

> The system has a high-
>   -performance component

I've read [babel: Adding ngerman' s language shorthands to english as the main document language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27198/babel-adding-ngermans-language-shorthands-to-english-as-the-main-document-l), and Stefan's answer to [What's the benefit of loading babel when writing in English?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27740/whats-the-benefit-of-loading-babel-when-writing-in-english), and thought this would do the trick:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman,british]{babel}
\useshorthands{"}
\addto\extrasbritish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
\selectlanguage{british}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Normal hyphenation, to illustrate:\\ 
\begin{minipage}{80pt}
Lala High"=performance.
\end{minipage}
\\[2pc]
\begin{minipage}{80pt}
Lalala lalala High"=performance.
\end{minipage}
\\[2pc]
My best guess:\\
\begin{minipage}{80pt}
Lala High"="~performance.
\end{minipage}
\\[2pc]
\begin{minipage}{80pt}
Lalala lalala High"="~performance.
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

It looks like the sequence `"="~` is close to what I want, but it suppresses hyphenation of the parts.

I've now spent about two hours trying all kinds of combinations, but as I don't really understand what I'm doing, I thought it better to ask, here, someone who actually *knows*.

I could, of course, use the `\discretionary` command, but I'd prefer it to be automatic.

BTW, typographical criticism is welcome (such as "don't *do* that!"),
but I'd still like to know, even if just out of curiosity.

Comment: `"="~` would be a wrong hyphenation of compound words in german and I suppose in english, too.

Comment: @Herbert: Are you saying my sample quote at the top is terminally incorrect typography? (Just to clarify your comment, which you have every right make...). Or just a question of style?

Comment: `High"=performance` is correct, only one dash, hyphenated or not

Comment: Sincere condolences on the death of your pet sabre-tooth.
 - I have not seen `text- newline -text` in German, thus I would not advise it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\useshorthands{"}
\makeatletter
\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{";}{\discretionary{-}{-}{-}\bbl@allowhyphens}
\makeatother
\addto\extrasbritish{\languageshorthands{ngerman}}
```

Now `";` (choose another shorthand, if you prefer) will do what you're looking for:

```
\begin{minipage}{80pt}
Lalala lalala High";performance.
\end{minipage}
```

will typeset as

> Lalala lalala High-
>    -performance.

but

```
\begin{minipage}{80pt}
Lala High";performance.
\end{minipage}
```

will typeset as

> Lala   High-per-
>   formance.

*Don't do it*. :)