# Text out of margins

Tags: line-breaking, classicthesis

I don't know why, but a line in my text is out of margins.

[image]

How can I avoid this issue?

I'm using `classicthesis` in TeXworks.

Edit: with the command

```
\overfullrule=5pt
```

I can see a black square where this issue appear.

Here a [MWE](http://baduel.altervista.org/stackoverflow/mwe.tex) and [`myclassicthesis-preamble`](http://baduel.altervista.org/stackoverflow/myclassicthesis-preamble.sty)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{myclassicthesis-preamble}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{microtype}

\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\small\textsc{#1}}

\overfullrule=5pt

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
\item[Service Delivery Framework] The infrastructure to create, publish, manage and consume FI services across their life cycle, addressing all technical and business aspects.
\item[Interface to the Network and Devices] The open interfaces to networks and devices, harmonizing the connectivity needs of services built on top of the platform.
\end{description}

Lastly, on the \emph{political dimension}, legal and legislative barriers presently hinder the efficient cross-border establishment of new innovative solutions due to complex or incompatible ICT policies in Europe.

\end{document}
```

Two possible problems: this line

```
\renewcommand{\descriptionlabel}[1]{\hspace*{\labelsep}\small\textsc{#1}}
```

and the modification in `myclassicthesis-preamble`(lines 63-70)

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{
            eulerchapternumbers,
            beramono,
            eulermath,          
            pdfspacing,         
            floatperchapter          
            }
{classicthesis}
```

in particular the option `pdfspacing`.

Comment: Can you try replacing the word `presently` with `present\-ly`or put `\hyphenation{pre-sent-ly}` in the preamble? Probably LaTeX doesn't know how to hyphen that word.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with the paragraph that illustrates the problem..

Comment: @percusse with `pre\-sent\-ly` works. But now I realized that there are a lot of these "out of margins". I must to redefine all the english words? =|

Comment: @PeterGrill I have added the MWE in my updated question.

Comment: You should also eliminate the extra stuff in `myclassicthesis-preamble`. For instance that contains settings for `listings` which is obviously not related to this question. And post the code here by editing you answer. It seems that if you add `\sloppy` it fixes these problems. If you don't want to add that thru your entire document just put it where you need it within a group (surround it with `{\sloppy ... \par}`)

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks, your solution seems to work. I've found online that `\sloppy` works until the `\fussy` command is called. Now I try to provide a very minimal example and post it in my question.

Comment: @percusse No problem. I also remove my comment in order to clean this post.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TeX doesn't hyphenate `presently` because of two concurring factors:

1. the word `present` cannot be hyphenated automatically, because it changes its syllables when it's a verb or a noun (just like `record`);
2. the right hyphenation minimum for English is set to three, that is, TeX is not allowed to leave less than three characters of a hyphenated word on the new line.

If we set `\righthyphenmin=2`, then `\showhyphens{presently}` gives `present-ly` as expected. Loading `ushyphenmax` via **hyphsubst** will not hyphenate `presently`, for the same reason, as `\righthyphenmin=3`.  Saying `\hyphenation{pres-ent-ly}` in the preamble would allow hyphenation as `pres-ently` (but not `present-ly`, because two letters are too few.).

In an emergency situation one can allow hyphenation by typing `present\-ly` that will override the default minimum.

The format set up by **classicthesis** is quite strict and your text shows the problems that can arise with long description labels. There's not very much to do apart modifying, if possible, the text. I would avoid `\sloppy` as much as possible, since it allows producing badly spaced paragraphs.

A better strategy is to use `\emergencystretch`: with the following modifications

```
\begingroup\emergencystretch=.3em
\begin{description}

\item[Service Delivery Framework] The infrastructure to create, publish, manage and consume
FI services across their life cycle, addressing all technical and business aspects.

\item[Interface to the Network and Devices] The open interfaces to networks and devices,
harmonizing the connectivity needs of services built on top of the platform.

\end{description}

\endgroup

Lastly, on the \emph{political dimension}, legal and legislative barriers present\-ly hinder
the efficient cross-border establishment of new innovative solutions due to complex or
incompatible ICT policies in Europe.
```

the text will be typeset without any overfull box and not overly bad spacing.

One should also note that **microtype** *is* loaded automatically by **classicthesis** (line 219 in `classicthesis.sty` says `\RequirePackage{microtype`).

Comment: While present has two possible hyphenations, presently has only one, "pres-ent-ly" (at least according to my dictionaries). Splitting up "-ly" probably wouldn't help much anyway in this situation because the complete "ly" is right of the border, and thus the hyphen would be, too. However "pres-ently" would not violate the three-letter-limit, so why would `\hyphenation{pres-ent-ly}` not help?

Comment: With `.4em` it works. I would also avoid `\sloppy` as much as possible. Anyway I realized that I have really too much overfull box, most of which are resolved if I don't use the option `pdfspacing` in `myclassicthesis-preamble`. What are the issues that I could find in the future if I decide to not load it?

Comment: From the [classicthesis documentation pag. 6](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/ClassicThesis.pdf): pdfspacing makes use of pdftex’ letter spacing capabilities via the microtype package. This ﬁxes some serious issues regarding math formulæ etc. (e. g., “ß”) in headers. I'm afraid about _serious_ issues.

Comment: @Baduel The option `pdfspacing` is relative to letter spacing; if it's active the letter spacing is done via **microtype**, otherwise via **soul**. I'd recommend the former.

Comment: @celtschk `\hyphenation{pres-ent-ly}` would give a hyphenation point `pres-ently`, but not `present-ly` because of `\righthyphenmin=3`. Good point, anyway.

Answer (score 8):

Edit: It seems like you have a few particularly unlucky places in your document, where only a `\sloppy` will help. Nonetheless, here is some information that might help understanding hyphenation a bit better and getting fewer of these places. Note that the following **only applies to American hyphenation patterns**, which is the default loaded by (La)TeX and loaded by `babel`'s options `english`, `american` and `usenglish`, which are [all the same](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12775/4012).

As has been mentioned, TeX doesn't know how to hyphenate *presently*. This can be seen by compiling a document containing `\showhyphens{presently}`; subsequently, the hyphenation points of *presently* will be put in the .log file -- turns out, there are none. As @percusse noted, adding `\hyphenation{pre-sent-ly}` to your preamble will solve the problem for this word, but you noted that there are more. So here's what else you could do:

#### Load the latest hyphenation patterns

Insert

```
\RequirePackage[english=usenglishmax]{hyphsubst}
```

even *before* your `\documentclass{...}` to load updated hyphenation patterns for `\usepackage[english]{babel}` (American patterns).

#### Include the known hyphenation exceptions by hand

The [*Hyphenation Exception Log*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/tb0hyf.pdf) (Nov 2010) is "the periodic update of the list of words that
TeX fails to hyphenate properly" (ibid., p. 1001). On page 1005, it confirms that TeX doesn't know how to hyphenate *presently*, and lists the desired hyphenation `pres-ent-ly`.

Here's the relevant paragaph on how to use this list of hyphenation exceptions:

> **Converting this list into machine-usable hyphenation exceptions**
>
> Werner Lemberg has created a script that will convert this article into a
>   real `\hyphenation` block that can be incorporated into a document
>   either directly or by inputting a file. His work has necessitated some
>   changes to the macros used to format the list, but the appearance of
>   the list will not change. Many inflected forms will be included
>   automatically, some evident in the printed version, but many included
>   silently. The script, `hyphenex.sh`, is a straightforward shell script
>   and is posted on CTAN, in [`tex-archive/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/)
>   The output of the script is posted in the same area as `ushyphex.tex`.

(ibid., p. 1001)

Besides that, I second Peter's suggestion of using the `microtype` package, which improves hyphenation in general and gives your document a more even grayness factor.

Comment: This solution can be used for hyphenation problem. However I also have the overfull problem in words not hyphenated (see my example). The `microtype` package is, in any case, loaded by the `classicthesis` package. Finally, is `english=ukenglish` the right option for `hyphsubst` for uk english?

Comment: With the unhyphenated words, I'm afraid `\sloppy` (and a timely `\fussy`) will be your only help. The `hyphsubst` is only available for `english`, which equals `usenglish`; afaik there aren't any updated hyphenation patterns for British hyphenation.

Answer (score 6):

Without a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) it is difficult to know for sure.

The usual reason this occurrs is that TeX was not able to meet all the rules for spacing as per the `Overfull \hbox` messages.  One way to fix this is to add `\sloppy` which relaxes the rules for inter word spacing.  See the answers to [Why is text being placed beyond the specified line width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18210/why-is-text-being-placed-beyond-the-specified-line-width) for a more detailed explanation.

Or you could add `\usepackage{microtype}` to the preamble.  See the [microtype package documentation](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype)  for more details.

Comment: I have added the MWE in my updated question.

Comment: I was just about to suggest `microtype`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe LaTeX doesn't know how to hyphenate "presently"? In that case you can just tell it how to do so by writing it as `pres\-ent\-ly`.

Comment: I think that the right hypernation is `pre\-sent\-ly` (and it works). Now the question is: why I have a lot of these "out of margins" in my document? Is it possible that the default package for the hypernation doesn't spell english in a good way?

Comment: I would have thought so, too, but not being a native English speaker, I looked it up, and two dictionaries agree that it is hyphenated the way I wrote in my answer. I have no idea about the quality of the default LaTeX hyphenation rules for English.

Comment: In fact TeX doesn't know how to hyphenate _presently_, `\showhyphens{presently}` puts `presently` in the .log file, and it's listed in http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/tb0hyf.pdf (cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22867/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-english-hyphenation-exceptions), where it says the correct form would be _pres-ent-ly_.

Comment: @doncherry Ok I will use `pres\-ent\-ly` to avoid this issue. However I found other overfull problem in my text, probably related to `myclassicthesis-preamble` or the `\newcommand` specified.

Comment: @Baduel: I think the thing that'll influence these things most is the current textwidth / linewidth, with which you're just unlucky.