# correct the hyphenation

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

How to correct the hyphenation in my paper that is entirely wrong? For example, in my paper, there are wrong hyphenations like *result-s*, *s-mall*, *s-pace*, etc. How can I fix this problem. I don't use any package yet.

[image]

Sample Code:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

An alternative way is to add:

```
\righthyphenmin=3
```

Comment: Hi John, welcome to TeX.sx! Could you edit your question to include a small example document that shows the behaviour you describe?

Comment: use the `babel` package to load hyphenation patterns

Comment: As Thorsten said, load `\usepackage[english]{babel}`

Comment: Does TeX really break s-pace?

Comment: As an addition to @Sigur's comment: Some people recommend using either `british` or `american`, just to be really clear. Usually, `english` equals `american`, cf. [babel: english, american, USenglish](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12775)

Comment: @sigur, Thanks. It works pretty fine. Mytex really break s-pace. I don't know why these hyphenations are wrong.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Good to hear that Thorsten's/Sigur's suggestion works for you. Would you mind posting an example document nonetheless?

Comment: @PatrickGundlach -- The default settings for TeX's hyphenation of English-language words are `\righthyphenmin=3` and `\lefthyphenmin=2`. Hence, TeX will **never** hyphenate `s-mall`, `result-s`, or `s-pace` -- *unless* one or more of the hyphenation-related defaults have been reset explicitly.

Comment: @Jake, I really want to upload an illustrative example, but I was told that new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.

Comment: @JohnSmith: There you go, I upvoted your question in anticipation of your MWE :)

Comment: @Mico, great! That might be the problem in essence. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSmith: Could you also include the code for a minimal example document that leads to that output?

Comment: @Mico that's what I thought. - I wonder how the image in the question was created.

Comment: As Mico said the setting  `\righthypenmin` looks to have been set to 0. If it is set that way in your latex format something went badly wrong when it was installed. The other alternative is that your tex file resets it. Without sample code impossible to say which of these is the case.

Comment: Even without loading english/babel (and setting the ..hyphenmin to 0), TeX would never hyphenate `s-mall`. There must be something very fishy here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the words `small`, `space`, and `results` to get hyphenated as `s-mall`, `s-pace`, and `result-s`, somebody or something must have reset two of TeX's fundamental hyphenation-related parameters, viz., `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin`. For an English-language setting, the default values of these parameters are

```
\lefthyphenmin=2
```

and

```
\righthyphenmin=3
```

Something in your document must have managed to set both parameters to `1` (or possibly `0`). Be sure to either delete the commands that modify these two parameters or insert the two instructions above in your document (to reset the parameter values to their respective default values).