# openany for hepthesis

Tags: page-breaking, thesis, hepthesis

Hi I'm using the hepthesis template and I creates a empty page before any new chapter. Since it is build upon `scrbook`, is there anyway to use something like `openany`

```
\documentclass[openany]{hepthesis}
```

doesn't work...

Comment: How about the `twoside` option?

Comment: @pluton Thank you for your suggestion. `oneside` works. You can upgrade your comment to an answer if you wan't.

Comment: Apart from the `oneside` option this should work with `twoside`: `\PassOptionsToClass{openany}{scrbook}\documentclass[<your_other_options>]{hepthesis}`.

Comment: @Speravir. Cool this would be something like invoking a baseclass options if I understand it correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from setting in oneside mode with

```
\documentclass[oneside]{hepthesis}
```

the following works, if you want to stay in twoside mode:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{openany}{scrbook}
\documentclass{hepthesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% just for dummy text

\begin{document}
\chapter{Kantian Introduction}
\kant[1-3]
\chapter{Kantian Criticism}
\kant[4-5]
\end{document}
```

In this manner many options of `hepthesis` are passed in background to `scrbook`, but an option `openany` is not provided, hence the issue you observed.

Comment: It is recommended to specify the particular variant of `english` rather than leaving it to chance. (`english` aliases to different variants depending on the version of `babel`.)

Comment: @cfr: Where is this recommended? And perhaps hree in TeX.sx we should intentionally choose `english`? I would otherwise prefer to choose "German English". ;-)

Comment: It is because in earlier versions of `babel` `english` would refer to either `american` or `british` depending on the local `language.dat` and maybe the version of `babel`. So writing `english` would give different output for different people. Since the whole point is that you want your code to produce the same output wherever it is compiled, this is obviously bad. So writing `english` is a bad example to set. (I can't remember where I read this originally but the details of why are in various editions of `language.dat`.) Is there not a German `kantlipsum`? Then you could just use `german`...

Comment: I've also added an answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170657/39222 because all of the existing answers seem to ignore the problem ;).

Comment: @cfr: The part with German was fun … my English flavour is German … `kantlipsum` is English only, but `blindtext` is programmed by a German and has, of course, a German version. (“Blindtext“ is actually the German word for dummy text.)

Comment: Aha. Interesting. A bit hard on Kant, though... ;)

Answer (score 3):

The `oneside` option should work here.